# Allow User to see only their own post C# ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I am trying to create restrictions in my WebApp. I want to create that every registered and logged-in User can see only their own post and can not see, edit or delete other posts.
So far I try to follow some posts here but this post doesn't give me more information.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328580/how-to-allow-users-to-only-edit-their-details-in-a-catalog/21342174)

So only if the user is Register their should be able to see their own posts not another post from other users.
Anyone, how can tell me and guide me what Do I need to do?

P.S: I also look and the `[Authorize]` attribute is not the solution which I am looking.

Here is my code:

```
public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {

            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                }),
                ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
                Client = new Client()
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }

            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
                    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }



        public IActionResult Details(int? Id)
        {
            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault())
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var ticketType = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

Comment: You need to read about Authorization more deeply. [Authorize] attribute is a small part of its functionality - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @ЯрославВиталиевич Hmm, in which part do I need to be focuse on ?

Comment: @UnKnowUser do you have CreatedBy column on the Post?
If you do, every time you get a post by id also include the logged-in user id/email/username as filter on the Createdby field.

Comment: I have UserId include in my Model. But I want to hidde all posts which is not releted to user

Comment: If you have UserId already, you should be using that when grabbing all posts. EX: _dbcontext.Posts.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)

Comment: @Filipe Hmm I try this logic but doesn't work !

Comment: I agree with Filipe.You said it doesn't work.Do you mean you cannot get posts of current logged-in user with userId?Are the post table and the user table connected with userId?

Comment: Yea, exactly. It cannot get posts of current logged-in user. Yes, tables are connected with userId